# Covariance and Contravariance of Delegates

Tags: c#, delegates, covariance, contravariance

There is something I am not understanding about **covariance** and **contravariance** of **delegates**. What's the rationale behind flexibility to downcast parameters and to upcast return types

As an example, say we have

1. Person as a Superclass and Teacher as a Subclass of Person
2. ReturnPersonDelagate that represents a method that returns a person
3. TeacherParameterDelegate that represents method that take an employee object as a parameter

You can

1. assign a method that return a Teacher to ReturnPersonDelagate (upcasting)
2. assign a method that takes Person as a parameter TeacherParameterDelegate (downcasting)

I am a bit confused. What's the rationale behind this concept and why is downcasting supported implicitly?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want your code to be more flexible?

Comment: Because something that always returns a `Teacher` does, by definition, always return a `Person`. And similarly a method that can work with *any* `Person` can clearly work if only ever passed `Teacher`s. It's completely safe.

Comment: Your question might become clearer if you post actual code instead of descriptions of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes perfect sense. Take a look:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Del d = Method;
        var p = d(new Teacher());
    }

    public delegate Person Del(Teacher t);

    public static Teacher Method(Person p)
    {
        return new Teacher();
    }
}

public class Person {}
public class Teacher : Person {}
```

`Method` returns a `Teacher` object which is always of type `Person` but imagine you swap the types and make the `Del` return a more specific type and `Method` to return a more general type. The code would not work and would not make sense at all. But in this case, it does as you always get a correct type that can be converted implicitly to the return type of the `Del`. Also, the type of the parameter of the `Del` type is more specific than the one `Method` accepts as it also makes sense. If you would swap them for example you could invoke the `Method` with the incorrect type but in this case, it is fine as the `Teacher` object will always be of type `Person`.

Comment: **Thanks, the way I understood it from what you have just said is:**
When a delegate is called, it converts it's parameters to the method's parameters. So it can't push a General Class in delegate to a Specific Class method but it can push Specific class in delegate to General Class in method
On return, a method returns a value to the delegate, so it can implicitly convert a specific class in method to a general class in delegate (Teacher to Person) but not the opposite

Comment: You can look at it as a restriction (sort of). It basically represents an interface that you are exposing to the caller and the implementation detail along with the truly needed types of the `Method` is hidden by it. That way you can have the same implementation but more delegates that force the correct parameters in different places when it makes sense.

Comment: Brilliant, I have clear understanding. Thanks to you Harun